# Android : EditText Max Length is 10 , why?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to build an android app wich convert between Binary,Decimal,HexaDecimal,Octal,and Ascii 
my app runs correctly , all operations was converted sucsessfully
the problem is when i try to convert Ascii to Decimale i get the result but if i type a long ASCII text i get a crash. After many tests i noticed that the Decimale EditText cannot accept more than 10 numbers , i tried to set a maximum length to 20 but i get the same result.
Please Help me , i don't know where is the problem ?

Comment: Post your code. Do you have a TextWatcher set on your EditText?

Comment: Please post the XML if you think XML is the issue or the LogCat logs in case you are getting any exception or the code where you think is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a crash this might be caused by the variable type you're using for decimal value.

Is it an int? Try to change from int to long if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks i changed it from int to long and now the problem is solved.